# Get Result from mysql by vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm making a tool to help a company with there staff holiday (staff holiday calculator)

I connected myself by vb and its connection to the database but I can't get any result

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim conn As New api()
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter()
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT `Full_Name`, `Job`, `Free_Days` FROM `Holiday` WHERE `Username`= '@name'", conn.getConnection())

        command.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = api.id

        Try
            conn.getConnection.Open()
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.Fill(table)

            Dim sqlReader As MySqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            While sqlReader.Read()
                namee = sqlReader("Full_Name").ToString()
                job = sqlReader("Job").ToString()
                days = sqlReader("Free_Days").ToString()
                MsgBox(sqlReader("Full_Name").ToString())
            End While

            Label2.Text = "Name : " + namee
            Label3.Text = "Job : " + job
            Label8.Text = "Holiday Free Days : " & days
        Catch ex As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I didn't get any MsgBox and there is no error and the label text didn't change

Comment: You don't use a data adapter and a data reader.  It's one or the other.  Decide what you're actually trying to achieve and use the appropriate approach.  Check out my examples [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872).

Comment: @jmcilhinney can i have your discord please? or any social media account so i can contact with you

Comment: @jmcilhinney I already saw that example and I don't see any differences between my code and your example

Comment: I don't use social media and, even if I did, that's not what this site is for.  If you can't see the difference between my examples and your code, particularly after my comment, then you're just not looking.  In which one of my examples do I call `Fill` on a data adapter and `ExecuteReader` on a command?  None!  Do it properly and then, if it still doesn't work, tell us EXACTLY what does happen.  "*I can't get any result"* is NOT an adequate explanation of the problem.  Did you debug your code to see whether execution even enters your `While` loop?  If not, you haven't done enough yet.

Comment: The above is correct. Do you understand what `adapter.Fill(table)` does? It _fills_ (see, clue's in the name!) the `table` variable with the result of the query. No need to read it again afterwards. You can already get the data you need from `table`. Or alternatively, get rid of the adapter and just use the reader. Your choice. But using both makes no sense. I don't think you can have properly understood what the code you're using does, nor, it is clear, did you look carefully at the examples you were given a link to. Don't use code if you don't have at least a basic understanding of it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have MySQL, but based on MSSQL try something like this:

```
Dim namee, job, days As String
Dim commandText As String = "SELECT `Full_Name`, `Job`, `Free_Days` FROM `Holiday` WHERE `Username`= '@name'"
Dim conn As New api()
Using adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(commandText, conn.getConnection())
     adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = api.id

     Dim table As New DataTable()
     adapter.Fill(table)
     If table.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No rows found", "ERROR")
     Else
        With table(0)
            namee = .Item("Full_Name")
            job = .Item("Job")
            days = .Item("Free_Days")
         End With
      End If
 End Using
```